# Register KVO in UIView subclass, got "observation info leak" warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying subclass a UIView in which I want to add more subviews. Since I'm changing frame property of my view in code, I want my subviews to resize when this view is resized, so I've added the following code in my `initWithCoder:` method:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

And in the observation method, I'll reset view's frame manually. Everything works fine, but when I push some other view controller and move back, I got this message:

```
Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object.
```

So, how can I fix this? I know for sure that the observer is not removed, but there is not any `viewDidDisappear` stuff here. What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the observer for all added observers, So do like following code,

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" context:NULL];
}
```

Comment: I'm using ARC, is dealloc still be a possible option?

Comment: may be u can put it in "- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated" method and adding observer in - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: ARC won't allow `[super dealloc]` thats all

Comment: Thanks erik, the "viewDidDisappear:" method is in View Controller I guess, can I use it in UIView?